# How to combine generic tuple

Tags: typescript

I need to combine a tuple with two generics, but I do not know how to write it. I can do this for one generic type, but I have problems with two.

Example of the code:

```
type Value<TFirst, TLast> = {
  first: TFirst,
  last: TLast,
}

function combine<TFirst extends unknown[], TLast extends unknown[]>(...values: any): 
   Value<TFirst, TLast> 
{ 
   return undefined as any; 
}

function makeValue<TFirst, TLast>() {  return undefined as any; }

const test: Value<[string, number], [never, string]> = combine(
  makeValue<string, never>(), 
  makeValue<number, string>()
);
```

with `...values: [...{ [K in keyof TFirst]: K extends keyof TLast ? Value<TFirst[K], TLast[K]> : never }]` it doesn't work

Comment: Can you add more code/expected results or replace those `return` statements with what you intend for them to be? It's hard to tell what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: The example code here is distracting and confusing.  Why `never` as a tuple element? Why does `makeValue()` take no arguments?  What type is `makeValue()` supposed to return (the implementation returns `undefined`, so I can't use it to help guide my intuition here).  Similarly, what is `combine()` supposed to accept as arguments (since the only example you have is the output of `makeValue()` which is `any`, I can't be sure).  You say you can make it work with one generic type, but you're not showing that.  I'm sure you're asking for *something* but this just doesn't seem to be a [mre].